# web.py REST server: should the GET method return a dict() or string (json.dumps(mydict))?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, rest, web.py

```
class MyRestHandler:
    def GET(self):
        my_dictionary = <do work and get it>
        return my_dictionary
          OR
        return json.dumps(my_dictionary, indent=2, seperators(',',': '))
```

I intend for this Rest GET to be invoked by outside clients as well as to be reused by another method in the server class, like so:

```
class myOtherRestHandler:
    def GET(self):
        child_hdlr = MyRestHandler()
        my_dict (or string) = child_hdlr.GET()
        # massage this dict; merge with something else then return response
```

Comment: Point your web browser at the REST URL and see what it gives you.  You will probably prefer the `json.dumps()` result better.

Comment: What will be the MIME type of the content you return? `text/plain`, `text/html`, `application/xml`, `application/json`, ...?

Answer (score 0):

In a HTTP server you should return string as a response. If you want to reuse some parts of your code, put it into separate methods like

```
class MyRestHandler:
    def my_get():
        my_dictionary = <do work and get it>
        return my_dictionary

    def GET(self):
        return return json.dumps(self.my_get(), indent=2, seperators(',',': '))
```

In other class you can call:

```
class myOtherRestHandler:
    def GET(self):
        child_hdlr = MyRestHandler()
        my_dict (or string) = child_hdlr.my_get()
        # massage this dict; merge with something else then return response
```